# columns not found by java mariadb connection

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

i'm using java to insert some data into a mariadb database, but when i execute the statement, i receive an error

```
Unknown column 'SCHEDETYPE' in 'field list'
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=84) Unknown column 'SCHEDETYPE' in 'field list'
```

but in my db the columns exists.

i tried to extract the column names through this code:

```
            ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

            // get the column names; column indexes start from 1
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
              String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
              // Get the name of the column's table name
              String tableName = rsMetaData.getTableName(i);
              System.out.println("column name=" + columnName + " table=" + tableName + "");
            }
```

but i'm returning only 6 columns from db

```
column name=id 
column name=label 
column name=user_id 
column name=submitted 
column name=created_at 
column name=updated_at
```

where is the problem??
thank you

my query

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO test.sc_test "
                    + "(LABEL, SCHEDETYPE,SCHEDECURRENT,user_id,submitted,is_hibernated,bad_formed,is_valid,"
                    + "start_hibernation,namespaces,created_at,updated_at) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,null,0,?,?,365,?,?,null)";

            java.sql.PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            
            prest.setString(1, cst.getLabel());
            prest.setString(2, cst.getSchedeType());
            prest.setString(3, cst.getSchedeCurrent());
            prest.setInt(4, cst.getUser_id());
            prest.setInt(5, cst.getBad_formed());
            prest.setInt(6, cst.getIs_valid());
            prest.setString(7, namespaces);
            prest.setTimestamp(8, ts);
            prest.executeUpdate();
```

from db

```
field,type,null,key,default,extra
'id', 'int(11) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'label', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'SchedeType', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'SchedeCurrent', 'varchar(100)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'user_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'submitted', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'is_hibernated', 'int(1)', 'NO', '', '0', ''
'bad_formed', 'int(1)', 'NO', '', '0', ''
'is_valid', 'int(1)', 'NO', '', '0', ''
'start_hibernation', 'int(4)', 'NO', '', '365', ''
'namespaces', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', '', 'gml,xsi,xlink', ''
'created_at', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', 'current_timestamp()', ''
'updated_at', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: Check that you are looking at the same table and the same schema / database on the same database service.

Comment: i have only one schema!!

Comment: I suggested this because the **evidence** implies that there are two different "versions" of that database table.  How can that possibly be if you are looking at the same table / schema / database / service?  Answer: AFAIK, it is impossible.  Which implies that you are *somehow* looking at different tables or databases or services or ... something else like that.

Comment: How can i verify this?i am looking at the db that is on a virtual machine.maybe are there some grant problems?it can be possibile?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that grant problems would affect the schema that you can see.  But I'm not sure of the best way to check ... apart from things like checking that the connection URL is right, that the db host names are resolving to the same IP address, etc.

Comment: On my physical Machine I have one Virtual machine That contains the DB. I tried to make an insert only with the fields that I can see with java,and by This Way I can insert into database. It can be a problem about jdbc driver for Maria DB? Maybe it needs particular libraries?

Comment: You don't show the query for your rs(ResultSet).